# Show a custom text on WooCommerce variable products when no variation is selected

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, product-variations, availability

I have a product with different variations. To choose an variation two select fields have to be filled. However, the availability message is only shown when both select fields have a option selected. I want to show a general availability message as long as not variation is selected: "Choose location and date to see availability".

I know how to change the message with the "woocommerce_get_availability_text"-filter. But I don't know how to present this message right from the page load and which part of WooCommerce's JavaScript I have to change in order to make it work.

I think the following is necessary:

1. Adding `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">Choose location and date to see availability</div>` to  content-single-product.php, so that the general message is shown right at the page load.
2. Add some JS which puts the `in-stock` and `out-of-stock` messages to the div as soon as a variation is selected. The JS has also to take care that the general message gets display again as soon as no variation is selected anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a custom text on variable products when no variation is selected use the following:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'display_variation_availability_message_js' );
function display_variation_availability_message_js() {
    global $product;

    $custom_text_html = sprintf('<div class="wc-availability" style="display:none">%s</div>',
        __('Choose location and date to see availability', 'woocommerce')
    );

    wc_enqueue_js("const a = '.wc-availability';
    $('.single_variation_wrap').prepend('{$custom_text_html}');
    $('form.cart').on('show_variation hide_variation', function(e) {
        e.type === 'show_variation' ? $(a).hide() : $(a).show();
    });");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

To target specific **variable products** only, replace in the function:

```php
    global $product;
```

with:

```php
    global $product;

    // Here below define the targeted variable product IDs in the array
    $specific_products_ids = array( 15, 37, 108 );

    if ( ! in_array( $product->get_id(), $specific_products_ids ) ) return;
```

---

Edit:

As the existing **parent** `<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">` for `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">` child element, get hidden (slideDown usage by WooCommerce), when there are no variations selected **you can not use it to display your custom div inside** `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">`.

It's not really possible to change the behavior slideUp / slideDown that WooCommerce is doing on `<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">`, without editing the WooCommerce JS files.

Here is a revisited code version using a `<div>` container and `slideUp()` / `slideDown()` methods instead of `show()` / `hide()` methods:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'display_variation_availability_message_js' );
function display_variation_availability_message_js() {
    global $product;

    $custom_text_html = sprintf('<div class="vcontainer" style="display:none">'.
        '<div class="wc-availability">%s</div></div>',
        __('Choose location and date to see availability', 'woocommerce')
    );

    wc_enqueue_js("$('.single_variation_wrap').prepend('{$custom_text_html}');
    $('form.cart').on('show_variation hide_variation', function(e) {
        e.type === 'show_variation' ? $('.vcontainer').slideUp(200) : $('.vcontainer').slideDown(200);
    });");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

This doesn't sole the problem as you would like in your comment, but it uses the same behavior as WooCommerce.

Comment: The solution goes in the right direction. However, loading a second <div> and not reusing the existing one results in some visual effects in the design.

The problem is that WC uses `slideUp( 200 )` and `slideDown( 200 )` to show/hide `.woocommerce-variation`. Is there any way to change this behavior?

The perfect solution would be to show `.woocommerce-variation-availability` from the beginning and conditionally change its content. I tried to overwrite the WC-jQuery behavior but it doesn't work.

Comment: As the existing **parent** `<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation">` for `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">` child, get hidden (slideDown) when there are no variations selected, you can not use it to display your custom div inside `<div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">`. **I have added an edit in my answer.**